# split file in unix and save the file names in a text file

Tags: shell, unix

I'm new to unix scripting. I have a requirement to split a file and list the filename of those files in a text file.

Any idea how to do this?

I have the script below but it's not working properly. It is splitting the file but its not saving the filenames in a text.

```
split -l ${SPLIT_COUNT} ${OUTPUT_FILE} ${SPLIT_OUTPUT_FILE} >> split_file_name.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this :

```
mkdir tempDir
split -l ${SPLIT_COUNT} ${OUTPUT_FILE} tempDir/${SPLIT_OUTPUT_FILE}
ls -l tempDir > split_file_name.txt
```

Comment: Hi Amey, Thank you. What if the directory already has files in it? it will be included in ls -l output right?

Comment: yes, but this is temporary dir which will only store your spitted file

Comment: Sorry, one last thing. I tried your suggestion above. It is including the split_file_name.txt in the output. How to exclude?

Comment: It should not include split_file_name as we are only doing `ls` on tempDir, anyway you can do `grep -v split_file_name` to exclude it